# Why the dist folder in .nuxt is deleted after I executed pm2 for server side rendering?

Tags: windows, deployment, nuxt.js, pm2

Currently I am using pm2 and nodejs on windows to deploy nuxt.js project. Below are my steps:

1. Build project with `npm run build`
2. Copy 【.nuxt, static, nuxt.config.js, package.json】 to a new folder call prod01
3. In prod01 folder, execute `npm i` to install dependencies and use `npm run start` to check if everything works fine.
4. Then, I config nginx, install pm2 and use `pm2 start node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js --name prod01` to start my project. (I've tried a lot of pm2 commands and this works for me)

However, after I use above `pm2 start` command, the dist folder in .nuxt has been deleted, and all I can see on

[image: my web page was like this]

because dist in .nuxt was not existed. 
 
Does anyone have any ideas about how this happened? My nuxt.config setting like meta description is still there, and I can open the web pages. 
Or is there any solutions except using docker, that can also do server side rendering? Or maybe I should try using docker?

Please help me, thank you!

Comment: could this help you? [how to deploy nuxt app on vps](https://blogxon.com/articles/how-to-deploy-nuxt-on-a-vps)

Comment: My steps are similar to the article, but it didn't work, thank you for sharing the article!

Comment: what doesnt work ca i may help u?